# Geometry and tangent-chord theorem problem?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

According to the figure, CA is tangent to the circle, centre O, at A. ABT and POT are straight lines.

**Question:**

Given that BT is equal to the radius of the circle, prove that:

1. $\angle ABP = 3 \angle OBP$
2. $\angle POA = 3 \angle BOT$
3. $\angle OBT = 2 (\angle BTO + \angle CAB)$

[image]

**My attempt:**

- $\angle AOP = 2 \angle ABP. $
- $\angle OBP = \angle OPB.$
- $\angle CAB = \angle APO.$
- $\angle BOA = 2 \angle APB.$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: prove that: 1. Angle ABP = 3 time of Angle OBP 2. Angle POA = 3 times of Angle BOT 3. Angle OBT = 2 times of (Angle BTO + Angle CAB)

Comment: Have you made any attempt? Please add an attempt so we can help you with where you might've got stuck

Comment: Yes, I have edited the original post to include my attempts.

Comment: Use the isosceles properties of BOT, AOB and AOP to relate the angles along with the AOP = 2* ABP. That should solve all of them

Comment: I still did not manage to get it. Can you give me a couple of initial steps so that I can follow through from there?

Answer (score 1):

1. $$\measuredangle ABP=\measuredangle OPB+\measuredangle OTB=\measuredangle OPB+\measuredangle TOB=$$
   $$=\measuredangle OPB+\measuredangle OPB+\measuredangle OBP=3\measuredangle OBP.$$
2. $$\measuredangle POA=\measuredangle OTB+\measuredangle OAB=\measuredangle OTB+\measuredangle OBA=$$
   $$=\measuredangle OTB+\measuredangle OTB+\measuredangle BOT=3\measuredangle BOT.$$
3. $$\measuredangle OBT=\measuredangle OAB+\measuredangle AOB=\measuredangle ABO+2\measuredangle CAB=$$
   $$=\measuredangle BTO+\measuredangle BOT+2\measuredangle CAB=2(\measuredangle BTO+\measuredangle CAB).$$

Answer (score 0):

a):

$BOT=2PBO$

$ABO=2BOT=4PBO$

$ABP=ABO-PBO=4PBO-PBI=3PBO$

b):

$ABP+\frac{1}{3}ABP=2BOT$

$\frac{4}{3}ABP=2BOT$

$ABP=\frac{1}{2}POA$

$\frac{4}{3}(\frac{1}{2}POA)=2BOT$

Therefore:

$POA=3BOT$

c):

$ OBT=AOB+OBA$

$AOB=2ABP=2CAB$

$OBA=2BTO$

Therefore:

$OBT 2(CAB+BTO)$